# ¿Cómo convertir una imagen svg triste a feliz?

Tags: svg

Me encontré una imagen triste que la estoy usando por el direccionamiento de un Error 404, pero para datos correctos me gustaría convertir la carita en un rostro feliz, estuve buscando el mismo modelo pero no tuve éxito.

Comprendo que las imágenes `svg` son configurables por los códigos que se basan en la imagen.

```
<svg width="134" height="134" viewBox="0 0 134 134" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#eee" d="M1 67.388c.019 36.919 29.394 66.243 66.32 66.208 36.871-.035 66.285-29.472 66.272-66.322C133.58 30.515 103.994.979 67.208 1 30.383 1.021.981 30.503 1 67.388zm40.332 19.774c-.001-5.624 1.68-5.857 6.035-5.941 4.615-.091 5.879 1.391 5.885 5.941.005 4.635-1.426 5.956-5.988 5.954-4.646-.002-5.932-.632-5.932-5.954zm5.683-46.129c4.745 0 6.41.813 6.222 5.768-.159 4.2-.727 6.398-5.692 6.235-4.257-.139-6.411-.852-6.1-5.772.252-3.983 0-6.505 5.57-6.23zm42.203-7.042s3.979 3.479 5.616 5.05c-21.936 22.036-13.345 44.103-.445 57.111.001 0-2.744 3.34-4.633 4.948-17.013-11.334-24.77-47.625-.538-67.109z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ja, Ja... No es perfecta pero sonríe. He cambiado algunos números negativos en positivos. Me he divertido mucho. Gracias.

```html
<svg width="134" height="134" viewBox="0 0 134 134" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#eee" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
  M1 67.388
  c.019 36.919 29.394 66.243 66.32 66.208 
  c36.871-.035 66.285-29.472 66.272-66.322
  C133.58 30.515 103.99 4.979 67.208 1 
  C30.383 1.02 1.981 30.503 1 67.388z
  m40.332 19.774
  c-.001-5.624 1.68-5.857 6.035-5.941 
  c4.615-.091 5.879 1.391 5.885 5.94 
  c1.005 4.635 -1.426 5.956 -5.988 5.954
  c-4.646 -.002 -5.932-.632 -5.932-5.954z
  m5.683-46.129
  c4.745 0 6.4 1.813 6.222 5.768
  c-.159 4.2 -.727 6.398 -5.692 6.235
  c-4.257-.139 -6.411-.852 -6.1-5.77
  c2.252-3.983 0-6.505 5.57-6.23z
  m42.203-7.042
  s3.979 3.479 5.616 5.05
  c 21.936 22.036 13.345 44.103 .445 57.11
  c1.001 0 2.744 3.34 4.633 4.948
  c 17.013-11.334 24.77-47.625-.538-67.109z"/></svg>
```